# Boolean fields in MySQL Django Models?

Tags: python, mysql, django, boolean

At Django, [a boolean field in MySQL is stored as a TINYINT](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/). When I retrieve it, I get 0 or 1. Shouldn't I get False or True? Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I DID read: MySQL users.. on the link provided.

Answer (score 7):

You could create your own method for your model that evaluates this for you:

```python
class User(models.Model):
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=1)

    def is_active(self):
        return bool(self.active_status)
```

Then any tests you perform against this field could just reference the method instead:

```python
>>> u.is_active()
True
```

You can even make this into a property:

```python
class User(models.Model):
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=1)

    @property    
    def is_active(self):
        return bool(self.active_status)
```

so that users of the class don't even have to know that it's implemented as a method:

```python
>>> u.is_active
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the above method adapted for `NullBooleanField`:

```
result = models.NullBooleanField()

def get_result(self):
    if self.result is None:
        return None
    return bool(self.result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a situation you anticipate that this will cause different behaviour just based on the types?

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> u=User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u.is_active
1
>>> u.is_active==1
True
>>>
```

The reasons why boolean columns return 1 or 0 are on the link in your question.

Comment: Your example should have been: u.is_active == True

Comment: Is it possible to implicity covert the boolean fields to True or False instead of 1 or 0

Comment: Juanjo, I listed that as an example how to achieve True or False result.
Rama, I guess it should be possible by modifying Django's model code, but I'm not aware of such solution.